# How to properly call drush command from another drush command?

Tags: 8, drush

I have a drush command that does some stuff and at the end of its execution I want to invoke `twig-compile --uri=foobar.com`. When I call `drush_invoke('twig-compile')` I get error about unknown arguments(those were passed to my drush command). I tried things like this before invoking the command `drush_set_context('options', ['uri', 'foobar.com']);` but no success yet.

How should I reset the options so twigc won't complain about them or how do I invoke the twigc command directly with the uri argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use drush_invoke, you should first use `drush_set_option('strict', FALSE);` to turn off strict option checking for the subcommand.  `drush_invoke` runs a subcommand in the same process, which can be more efficient; however, there are a number of ways that this can go wrong, so it is often better to use `drush_invoke_process` instead, to run the subcommand in its own process.  If you do this, there is no need to disable strict option handling.

`drush_invoke_process('@self', 'twig-compile', $args, $options);`.